# How in html to colour only the unused part of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a webpage. I want the code

```
<header>
    Some content
</header>
<body>
    More content
</body>
```

to be placed in the middle of the screen and occupy only a fraction of
the screen's width. I want the rest of the screen to be coloured grey.

Basically, I want the page to have a similar look as [this one](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/).

What would be the simple way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap all your content in 1 main div and give it a max-width, for example 1200px. Then set color to your body like:

```
    body {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    #main {
        max-width: 900px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes seemingly complex problems have the most simplest of solutions. +1 to this line of though.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your content in container div and specify the width. Set the background color of body to gray.
You will need to use `margin:auto;`, `left:0;` and `right:0;` for the container div to make it center.

```css
body{
  background-color:lightgray;
}

#container{
  width:400px;
  background-color:white;
  margin:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

header{
  height:200px;
}

.more-content{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <header>
    Some content
  </header>
  <div class="more-content">
      More content
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you would set the background color of the `<body/>` element in gray and the child elements of it to white:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>

body {
  /* make the <body/> stretch to the whole window */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* center all contents */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
    
  /* set the background color */
  background: lightgray;
}

body > div {
  /* to make it look better */
  padding: 20px;
  
  /* set the background color */
  background: white;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you're interested to learn more about flexboxes [this article is a good starting place](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).